# How to make a table scrollable and have fixed height

Tags: html, css

I would like to have a table on my website that is a fixed size and allows for scrolling. Right now the table takes up the entire page because it has many rows of data. I want to limit the height and make the table scrollable so it does not take up the whole page. Here is my code for the table. I tried to wrap the table in a div and set overflow: auto but that did not seem to work.

```
<table class="table table-dark">
    <thead class="thead-light">
    <tr>
        <th>State</th>
        <th>County</th>
        <th>Total cases reported</th>
        <th>Changes since last day</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr th:each="locationStat : ${locationStats}">
        <td th:text="${locationStat.state}"></td>
        <td th:text="${locationStat.country}"></td>
        <td th:text="${locationStat.latestTotalCases}">0</td>
        <td th:text="${locationStat.dailyChange}">0</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: give your div a height that make your overflow work

Answer (score 0):

Set table height fixed. Something like 300px or so. It makes a virtical scroll bar

Answer (score 0):

Try follow code

```
<table class="table table-dark table-responsive" style="height:500px;width:100%">
    <thead class="thead-light">
    <tr>
        <th>State</th>
        <th>County</th>
        <th>Total cases reported</th>
        <th>Changes since last day</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr th:each="locationStat : ${locationStats}">
        <td th:text="${locationStat.state}"></td>
        <td th:text="${locationStat.country}"></td>
        <td th:text="${locationStat.latestTotalCases}">0</td>
        <td th:text="${locationStat.dailyChange}">0</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```